# GraphQL: Unknown field "employee": The parent selection or operation does not resolve to a valid schema type

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to define a simple GraphQL query that gets a list of all employees at a given department. The query looks like this:

```
export const QUERY_DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEES = gql`
    query Employees($departmentId: ID) {
        employee(departmentId: $departmentId) {
            ...EmployeeFields
        }
    }`
```

IntelliJ is indicating an error on `Employee`: `Unknown field "employee": The parent selection or operation does not resolve to a valid schema type` . Is something missing from my schema.graphql, or is something not being read? This is what's in my schema.graphql file:

```
type Employee {
    username: String!
    fullName: String!
    lastName: String!
}
```

I've tried making the query simpler by removing the arguments but the error persists. I've explicitly made my `documents` parameter in graphql.config.yml empty, and this is what that file looks like now:

```
schema: ./schema.graphql
documents: []
```

Comment: You have not shown your `EmployeeFields` fragments, but the actual error message suggests that your top-level `employee` field does not exist in `Query`. Since you expect a list, is it maybe `employees`?

Comment: `EmployeeFields` is as follows:

```
fragment EmployeeFields on Employee {
        username
        fullName
        lastName
}
```

Perhaps it's not clear to me, where do I define `employee` or `employees` in `Query`?

Comment: The same as you define any other field in your server schema

Comment: Should this definition be added to schema.graphql then? This doesn't resolve the error:


```
type Employees {
    employee: [Employee!]
}
```